# Salesforce, implementing questionnaires

Tags: salesforce

We have a customer who want to implement reasonably complex questionnaires in salesforce. Currently they use excel spread sheets. The questionnaires will have text, multiple choice and yes/ no answers and they will want the ability for an admin user to add and remove questions, rules etc. The answers to some questions will mean other questions will or will not be asked. The answers will also be combined to produce a score for the user.

I never even heard about Salesforce until yesterday. I've had a look around their web site but can't find the page "Implement questionnaires like this." Is this the sort of thing salesforce can do and if so please can you point me in the direction of the documentation for developing this sort of solution.

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce doesn't provide questionaire or survey functionality on its own.  You could either develop your own solution using [Visualforce and Apex](http://developer.force.com/), or use a partner application.  My company uses [Zoomerang for Salesforce](http://www.zoomerang.com/salesforce/) and it integrates nicely with Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this successfully.

1. Create sObject that holds Questions
2. Create sObject that is junction of question and user called "Answer"
3. Create visualforce page that displays questions and allows the user to input answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the LWC component for this or you can achive this using flows in salesforce . This will provide a very good User interface and very interactive.
You need:
1. create objects
2. refer the trailhead trainings for lwc - it explains very well